# Accessing attribute of a returned getminininfo call to a bitcoinrpc object

Tags: python, object, attributes, rpc, bitcoin

I am coding a program that requires access to bitcoin and other cryptocurrency wallets on a remote server. I have it all coded pretty much but one error keeps popping up that causes divide by 0 (wonderful right?) 
I am accessing the wallet via this line:
`conn = bitcoinrpc.connect_to_remote('####', '###', host=###', port=port)`

I assure you the user, pass and ip are all correct. I then proceed to do this

`wallet_response = conn.getmininginfo
                self._difficulty = wallet_response.difficulty
                print 'difficulty'
                self._networkhash = wallet_response.networkhashps
                print 'network hashrate'
                self._blockcount = wallet_response.blocks
                print 'blocks'`

but it says that "'function' object has no attribute etc"

I have tried to iterate through, accessing attributes by [] but I cannot get it. I thought that .getmininginfo returned an object that i could access the attributes but it returns a function? I have read through the documentation and looked through the code and cannot come up with how to access them.

Anyone seen this before or know how to access the attributes in a function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are missing parens:

```
conn.getmininginfo
```

should be

```
conn.getmininginfo()
```

Comment: that helped. Now I am getting a connection error but i think that is because the server is not operating properly right now.